# Online storage service with 15GB that works well on Linux

Tags: linux, backup, file-synchronization, cloud-service

I mainly use [Google Drive Desktop](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive) for backing up pictures, and files on Windows, but I have yet to find a good alternative to use on Linux/Ubuntu. I know about [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/), however they don't have a large amount of free space and their prices for upgrading are, well, pricey. I am mainly looking for a tool that can sync files so I don't lose my work in case my computer has a meltdown.

I am not *just* looking for a free service. I am looking for something that has cheaper upgrade rates than dropbox, and also has more default, free space.

Is there an alternative to Google Drive that isn't Dropbox?

I need about 15GB.

Comment: Which features do you need? Just file syncing? Or also file sharing/publishing/editing?

Comment: @Olli Mainly just syncing so I don't lose my work.

Comment: For just syncing, see http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/129/syncing-files-between-computers

Comment: Syncing with what? Do you want to synchronize between two (or more) computers that you own, or do you want to rent storage on the cloud? Given that there are already three answers about cloud-based storage, if that isn't what you meant after all, ask a different question (unless http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/129/syncing-files-between-computers suits you).

Comment: @aman207, Why not use the web interface Google Drive provides?

Comment: @Pacerier Because then my files aren't automatically backed up. Usually I put my programming stuff on cloud backups and its a bit of a pain to copy every little file that I changed

Comment: @aman207, But Google Drive has APIs for scripting right? Which means everytime you do a file save, the file would be immediately uploaded.

Comment: @Pacerier I'm having a hard time actually finding a _good_ alternative for linux. Honestly, I'll just wait for Google to release their version.

Comment: @aman207, I mean the API is there. You could an app yourself that make use of the API.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### [Mega](https://mega.co.nz/)

Mega is an excellent service I've been using since its initial launch. I'd highly recommend it if not just for its usability and the 50gb free storage you get. One thing I love about Mega is the file manager. It's easy to use, understand, and works in browser.

[image: Mega File Manager]

Most importantly, Mega functions in most [modern web browsers](https://mega.co.nz/#blog_1). A Mega client with file syncing is also available for Windows, Mac and Linux. Mobile apps are available on Android, IOS, and Blackberry.

### Features:

- 50gb free storage
- Accessible from any modern browser (mobile and desktop clients are also available)
- File Sync client available on [Windows, Mac, and Linux](https://mega.co.nz/#sync)
- Plans starting from 9.99 € a month for 500gb storage and 1tb bandwidth
- End-to-end file encryption
- Easy file sharing and contact management

### Cryptography

One interesting thing to note about Mega is that, to quote Wikipedia:

> Dotcom has said that data on the Mega service will be encrypted client-side using an advanced AES algorithm. Since Mega does not know the encryption keys to uploaded files, they cannot decrypt and view the content. Therefore, they cannot be responsible for the contents of uploaded files.

However, I would not trust that Mega, if compelled by, say, a subpoena, could not obtain a user's master key and decrypt their files in their entirety. See also [MEGApwn](http://nzkoz.github.io/MegaPWN/).

<sub>When uploading to any file storage platform you should always expect that your data will be immediately accessible to others without your consent, and that it may, at any point in the future, become unavailable to you without warning.</sub>

Comment: Works through browser means... "manually syncing files"

Comment: @Olli That would be what the [Sync client](https://mega.co.nz/#sync) is for. Unfortunately, it is only available on Windows currently, but will be available on Linux and Mac in the near future.

Comment: Oh, cool, I have missed that.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore Really nice suggestion. I will keep an eye on it for when the Linux and Android clients show up.

Comment: Using a service run by Kim Dotcom for backup purposes is... unwise to say the very least. Ask those who used Megaupload how well that worked out.

Comment: @chx That would he because the US government has no sense of law or boundaries. Any upload service including Google Drive and Dropbox runs the same risk.

Answer (score 10):

**Copy is no longer an option since [Copy and CudaDrive services will be discontinued on May 1, 2016](https://techlib.barracuda.com/CudaDrive/EOL)**

---

Since you want 15GB space and Dropbox like functionality in Linux, I would say [Copy](https://www.copy.com/home/) is your best option right now. With a free account, you get to receive 15GB and access from Windows, Linux, Mac and Android.

### Upgrade policy

The upgrade costs work like this:

- 250GB - $10/month or $99/year
- 500GB - $15/month or $149/year

If you want to start with **20GB** you can use this [link](https://copy.com?r=NBadmV) to sign up. It is an invite from me.

Besides, every time you invite someone to copy, you get an extra 5GB.

### Usage

I installed Copy in December 2013 and am using it for non essential files that do not get changed often. I have two Linux boxes to sync. I report no problems what so ever but I am not giving it a heavy usage yet.

Comment: Since installing `copy` I have found that roughly every other time I boot my machine it opens two dolphin windows to the copy folder without any instruction from me to do so.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Do you want to add your take in the answer?

Comment: Here's a link that talks about installing Copy with a PPA for Ubuntu or Linux Mint: www.webupd8.org/2014/06/install-copycom-client-in-ubuntu-or.html.

Not sure if you want to add this to the answer but thought I would share just in case.

Comment: Hello @Kenny. I can add it but, feel free to do it without asking if it makes sense.

Comment: Copy is down now, it's ending, So might as well add that to the answer @AlexandreMartins

Comment: @Adityaultra Thanks for calling my attention. Doing it now.

Answer (score 9):

## Amazon S3

**Pluses**

- Reliable company, won't disappear overnight, not associated with piracy or on anyone's sh*t list.
- Works great on Linux, Windows, Mac, in a browser plugin, on the command line, and other odd places.
- Well known service, used in thousands of businesses
- Pay for what you use means not having to choose an account size
- Virtually unlimited capacity
- Access to files via web browser, command line tools and various libraries
- Option to publish a directory as its own web site
- Small accounts are OK and can be free to very inexpensive (~$10/yr for storing 10-15Gb).

**Minuses**

- You will need to copy/paste security keys out of the web interface into configuration files for the other tools you might want to use.
- You will need to write a cron job to sync automatically.
- No spending limit, so don't let bad guys get your keys.
- Charged for outbound transfer after free 1GB  ~ around $0.12/GB.
- You need to know what you are doing, although there is documentation.

Amazon S3 is more of an industrial B2B solution but is usable. Many of the consumer services are built on top of S3.  As such, it is a bit more involved to set up and works more like a secure file transfer than as a virtual drive.  You get charged monthly for traffic and storage.  I think inbound traffic is free but outgoing could be expensive if you have lots of traffic for restores.

One thing that makes it different from a consumer service is that there are no plans or usage limits, at least not any you can see. For storage, there is virtually infinite capacity.  Instead, you are charged for usage. This means
there is a risk of being charged lots of money for someone stealing your account.  In practice, I've never heard of this happening, though surely it must.  It has never happened to me.  Some people, though, don't recommend S3 as a *web-hosting platform* because popularity or evildoers might run up a bill.  As a storage, only platform that is less of a problem provided that you keep your keys safe.

Currently, 5Gb of storage is free for new users for a year. The additional 10GB, if you are really going to use it, is currently $0.085/GB-month in Feb 2014.  So that's US$0.85/month or about $10 for the first year, for storage.  For traffic, incoming is free, and outgoing is 1GB/month free then currently $0.12/GB in Feb 2014.  I think they also give away a free micro-VPS for a year if you want a server, too, but that is a separate service (EC2).

Full details, see:  [S3 storage pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

Go to aws.amazon.com to sign up.

In ubuntu, install s3cmd to have a command line interface to upload/download files.  s3cmd includes a sync option.

From the s3tools man page, you get all of this:

> COMMANDS
>          s3cmd can do several actions specified by the following commands.
>
> ```
>    s3cmd mb s3://BUCKET
>           Make bucket
>
>    s3cmd rb s3://BUCKET
>           Remove bucket
>
>    s3cmd ls [s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX]]
>           List objects or buckets
>
>    s3cmd la
>           List all object in all buckets
>
>    s3cmd put FILE [FILE...] s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX]
>           Put file into bucket
>
>    s3cmd get s3://BUCKET/OBJECT LOCAL_FILE
>           Get file from bucket
>
>    s3cmd del s3://BUCKET/OBJECT
>           Delete file from bucket
>
>    s3cmd  sync  LOCAL_DIR  s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX]  or   s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX]
>    LOCAL_DIR
>           Synchronize a directory tree to S3
>
>    s3cmd du [s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX]]
>           Disk usage by buckets
>
>    s3cmd info s3://BUCKET[/OBJECT]
>           Get various information about Buckets or Files
>
>    s3cmd cp s3://BUCKET1/OBJECT1 s3://BUCKET2[/OBJECT2]
>           Copy object
>
>    s3cmd mv s3://BUCKET1/OBJECT1 s3://BUCKET2[/OBJECT2]
>           Move object
>
>    s3cmd setacl s3://BUCKET[/OBJECT]
>           Modify Access control list for Bucket or Files
>
>    s3cmd accesslog s3://BUCKET
>           Enable/disable bucket access logging
>
>    s3cmd sign STRING-TO-SIGN
>           Sign arbitrary string using the secret key
>
>    s3cmd fixbucket s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX]
>           Fix invalid file names in a bucket
> ```

Plus, you get another page of commands to manage publishing s3 files to the web,
if you want to make a website out of your files.

Configuration will require an S3 access key from your S3 account... and this isn't something you should leave lying around in an insecure environment such as a shared PC at work, a virtual server that might get hacked, a laptop you carry that is subject to theft etc., or else some scammer could use your s3 key and be deleting your files or perhaps using your credit card to finance his illegal download site until he gets you banned. One solution is to use `gpg --symmetric` to encrypt your dotfile with a passphrase and delete the dotfile when not in use.  I had posted some short 2-3 line scripts for this to the s3tools blog, but that site is not responding at the time I write this.

When s3cmd is not handy, you can use the aws web tool to upload/download files.

The only problem I have encountered with this service involved Verizon Mifi, and is probably a Verizon network limitation.  The Verizon portable broadband would drop the connection after transferring several hundred megabytes.  You can access Amazon S3 from virtually any location on the internet.  I have never seen a timeout or disconnect problem on a wired network.

Comment: Can you actually recommend using S3 for this? Have you used it? Any problems? Any idea how to automate syncing, instead of manually running `s3cmd`? Please read [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/86/youre-doing-it-all-wrong?cb=1) too.

Comment: 1. I just did; 2. Yes; 3. No.; 4. cron job? [find -newer](http://serverfault.com/a/113472/33903); 5. Would you like fries with that?

Comment: If you investigate Amazon, I suggest you pay close attention to Amazon Glacier. It's in that price list and at http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/ It's for data archiving, you pay very little for uploading, and more for downloading.

Comment: Glacier can be $0.01/Gb to store but it can be **insanely expensive to restore** from glacier.  Think archiving emails and file backups across a large Fortune 500 company in case of a lawsuit.  Maybe you never need them, but when you do.... The restore cost for glacier currently depends on how soon you want the data.  The traffic charge is based on the peak traffic multiplied by a window of time. S3 is reasonable but be careful with glacier.  Maybe AWS will revise their glacier pricing someday.

Comment: I'm currently using S3 to store my backups, but I'm less than comfortable with it. Amazon has a [very bad record](https://medium.com/@espringe/amazon-s-customer-service-backdoor-be375b3428c4) of falling victim to social engineering attacks, and it seems likely that a clever, targeted attack could close my account and destroy my backups, or at least make access to them difficult.

Answer (score 6):

I use [Jolicloud](http://www.jolicloud.com/), which is not one single cloud service, but a tool to 'merge' all these accounts to make one big space to keep all your stuff. Therefore, you can add almost *every single one* of the other answers to your Jolicloud account and have a big super-account.

The web-interface looks like this:

[image: Jolicloud UI]

Comment: That's really cool. I've never checked out Jolicloud before, but Joli OS did seem like a nice, crisp alternative to Chromium OS when last I heard about it.

Comment: Does it work well for this case? Is there Linux client? Does it actually work well on Linux, based on your experiences?

Comment: @Olli I'd assume it works well on Linux as there's an entire Linux distro built around it provided by the same company. That being said, there is no client from what I know. It's all in browser.

Answer (score 6):

I use [CrashPlan](https://www.code42.com/crashplan/) and it works well. At $60 a year you get unlimited storage -- it's more likely that your upload speed will limit you. I am at 200GB and growing.

CrashPlan runs on Linux cos it's written in Java. Java sometimes has performance issues but you can schedule your backups so your machine only gets loaded when you are asleep. As far as I am aware you can only do backups/restores with the supplied software (or the web site), they claim using a proprietary binary protocol.

Comment: could you add some details on what it can, maybe a screenshot of its file manager if it has any?

Comment: What are the limitations of CrashPlan? How stable is it? What technical means (protocols) does it offer to synchronize files?

Comment: @Gilles well, actually this is a bit tricky question, as it asks for online service, and uses Google Drive and Dropbox as examples, but in fact asks for online backup service. For that, protocols used for syncing files are not important, as there's client program available.

Answer (score 6):

If it's just for syncing, and you don't need space on the cloud, [bitorrent sync](http://getsync.com/) works brilliantly

- No information is stored on their servers
- unlimited sync - quite literally, the only limit is your internet connection and your hard drive
- Data transfer is encrypted
- No login required
- selective per folder sync - each share can be added to a new system by copying over a unique shared secret
- works with windows, linux( x86, arm and ppc), IOS and android
- webui for headless systems

Pair that up with a cheap VPS, or just any nas, or spare system(I use a raspberry pi with an external HDD) and you have a low-cost private synchronization system that works anywhere you have network access.

Comment: Asker explicitly asked for an *online storage service* though...

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: The way I have it set up, I have 30gb on a cheap VPS I can use to store stuff. I was also slightly more focused on "I am mainly looking for a tool that can sync files so I don't lose my work in case my computer has a melt down."

Answer (score 3):

[Box.com](https://www.box.com) gives a flat 10GB storage for a free account, but you are limited to 250MB files unless you pay for an upgrade, and size upgrades are also more expensive than Ubuntu One, costing $10 per month. As far as I can tell Box.com does not have an official Linux app, but there are ways to access their service using WebDAV, and there may be third-party applications to support it.

Comment: Do you have any experience with either of these? Can you actually recommend these? Please read [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/86/youre-doing-it-all-wrong?cb=1)

Comment: Ubuntu One, alas, is dead.

Answer (score 3):

May I recommend OneDrive? It meets your requirements of,

- Comes with 15 GB free
- Cheap rates with upgrade plans starting at 50 GB for just $1.99 a month.
- Works with Linux using this software, [onedrive-d](https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d-old)

## [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/) (free)

> OneDrive (formerly SkyDrive) delivers a satisfactory online file storage and sharing solution in a free and easy to use service. It has a design that is both attractive and functional.
>   OneDrive lets you edit your Microsoft Office documents online, it offers a lite version of three of the major softwares of the suite Word, Excel, and PowerPoint, so if you don't have the suite installed on your PC or Mac you can simply edit them online. OneDrive space starts at 7Gb (and for a short period it is able to extend this space up to 25Gb for free). It also has the cheapest online storage services. So you have full access to your documents on all your computers, wherever you are.

[image: OneDrive with onedrive-d]

Answer (score 2):

[ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) is open source and free to download, however, you host it yourself so it doesn't include the service, free or otherwise. You need to buy hosting space elsewhere >= 15gb. Or host it at home if you are up for that.

It has many of the features of dropbox or google drive but you are in control of everything.

Here is the [demo](http://demo.owncloud.org/index.php/apps/files).

Comment: OP specifically asked for **Online Storage**. ownCloud is an amazing sync tool but not cloud storage at all. However it can be set up to sync with Google Drive quite easily.

Comment: @danijelc You can host it on a cloud server if you really want to. The main feature he is asking for is Syncing.

Comment: That's the point OP is asking for Cloud storage not a client. ownCloud with some online/cloud storage.

Comment: @danijelc So you pay for some hosting, install ownCloud serverside software on it for free and install the desktop client and now you have your cloud storage. It may not be his exact question, but he may not have known this sort of option existed. It provides all of the features he is asking for.

Comment: I suppose I could've recommended Arvixe which is a server provider, providing owncloud specific servers. This is the storage, but I know for a fact that answer would have been shot down, because there are hundreds of options when it comes to who hosts your owncloud.

Comment: Well it would be a possibility the point is not to give half recommendation. You could update answer with Arvixe or any other cloud based storage compatible with ownCloud