# Synchronize files between three computers

Tags: windows, networking, file-synchronization

I'm looking for software to synchronize my projects files between my PC and my laptop, frequently or in real-time. I'm a videographer and a motion designer, so I have big files. The main goal is to I could be able to pick up my work on my laptop where ever I ended it on the PC, even though my PC is off, and vice-versa.

So I have a server with windows 7 on it and I though it could be manage the synchronization, so I could power off the PC or the laptop and still able to synchronize the latest modifications.

I was trying to osa synkron, but the multisnyc option didn't work for me. None of my files were copied.

Comment: How about dropbox?

Comment: Related: [Syncing files between computers?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/129/185) Though that one asks for MacOS/Ubuntu, the answer with Git-Annex works for Windows as well. @FranckDernoncourt Unlikely, quote: *I'm a videographer and a motion designer, so I have big files* The size provided by Dropbox might be a bit much limiting here ;)

Comment: Do you want to avoid going through a cloud (other people's computers)?

Comment: @Izzy ah, maybe… I have an unlimited account there so I forgot about this detail ;)

Comment: Yeah I would skip the cloud solutions, for practical and privacy reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only work within you own network and don't care about syncing when you outside of your network then I would suggest using a mapped network drive on each machine pointing to one file on your server.

however is you wanted it to work anywhere one drive or Dropbox would be good options but these both have a maximum amount of storage space without paying for more and since you have your own server you could look into using [owncloud](https://owncloud.org/) a free self hosted cloud storage program.(will require Linux like OS (virtual machine)). 
Its pretty straightforward to setup if you familiar with *nix systems

Answer (score 4):

Have alook at [BitTorrentSynch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_Sync). It's free, cross platform and will keep all of your devices in synch.

Note that you will be keeping multiple copies of each file, which is a consideration since you say that you have large files.

I like @MrDeanosupreamo suggestion of a shared network drive, but since you say that you want to access files on one machine while another is powered off, it would seem that you have no choice.

You will also be able to access your files on your 'phone, tablet, etc.

> BitTorrent Sync by BitTorrent, Inc is a proprietary peer-to-peer file
>   synchronisation tool available for Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS,
>   Windows Phone, Amazon Kindle Fire and BSD. It can sync files between
>   devices on a local network, or between remote devices over the
>   Internet via a modified version of the BitTorrent protocol.
>
> Although not touted by the developers as an intended direct
>   replacement nor competitor to cloud-based file synchronisation
>   services, it has attained much of its publicity in this potential
>   role.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_Sync) This is mainly due to the ability of BitTorrent Sync to
>   address many of the concerns in existing services relating to file
>   storage limits, privacy, cost, and performance